# table with asynchronous loading

Tags: html, ajax

My fetching time to my DB takes 3-5 secs. so for now I just want to have loading image or whatever to my table while my data is fetching. is it possible to do that in javascript?

Here my button to trigger the load and table to read:

```
<button style="float:right" type="button" onclick="LoadDB()" class="btn btn-primary">Load DB</button>

 <table class="sortable" id="DB">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Names</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

script to populate the data to table:

```
function LoadDB() {        

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/ReadDB',
            type: 'GET',

            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var row = '';
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    row += '<tr><td style="display:none;"  >' + item.Name + '</td><td>' + item.Age
                        + '</td><td width="50%">' + '<button style ="width:80px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Add </button >' + '</td></tr>';

                });
                console.log(row)
                $('.sortable#DB2 tbody').html(row); // override previous results              
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: May be use something like: https://datatables.net/. Same functionality already implemented there, why to invent the wheel. Otherwise you can definitely do that with `DOM` manipulations (just like `datatables` doing). Here is example to use: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

Comment: `AJAX` stands for 'Asynchronous JavaScript And XML'. You're asking for the default behavior of the function... Other JS functions still work while AJAX is loading -except you explicitely tell ajax to be synchronous-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ajax request as follows to show the loading image till the data is loaded from the database by calling the image_loader function.After getting ajax response the image will be replaced with data.

```
function image_loader()
{
$(".sortable#DB2 tbody").html("<img src='loading.gif' alt='Loading...' >");
}

function LoadDB() {        
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/ReadDB',
        type: 'GET',
        start: image_loader(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var row = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                row += '<tr><td style="display:none;"  >' + item.Name + '</td><td>' + item.Age
                    + '</td><td width="50%">' + '<button style ="width:80px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Add </button >' + '</td></tr>';

            });
            console.log(row)
            $('.sortable#DB2 tbody').html(row); // override previous results              
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });

}
```

For more information on start method in Jquery ajax you can look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxstart.asp)